# Error on symfony 5.4 : Could not find the entity manager for class 'x'

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Today i tried to copy/past an entity from a project to an other.
First i tried to create the entity with

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

And to copy/past the entity class into the file just created.
Didn't work and got this error message i can't figure out.

My configuration is a new symfony 5.4 project. And symfony 5.4 for the other project.
The only things that change is that in the first projet i used annotation system (@ORM\Table...) and the new one is attributes by default (`#[ORM\...`). But i used to use both on other projects and worked well.

I tried to change annotation to attribute and it works. But i would like to know how can i use both annotations and attributes on the project, it used to be the default value ?

My doctrine.yaml :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '14'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

What i tried :

- cache clear
- remove/create entity
- check on internet for some solutions
- check if `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` was in my file

What i tried :

- cache clear
- remove/create entity
- check on internet for some solutions
- check if `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` was in my file

Comment: Unfortunately you can use only one type of mapping per entity manager.  You can add `type: annotation` to your mapping section but at some point you just have to take the time to move to attributes going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony does not support both, you have to choose between of 2, so if you don't have any php version problem, both should fit